# Need help in the project "Arduino for audio processing"

Tags: arduino-uno, audio

I am following this link from Instructables site:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Input/

My question is:

Instead of using the Microphone Radioshack 33-3038, which is listed in the tutorial, can I use https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9964?

Kindly suggest if there any modifications required in other parts for the circuitry, if I go for Electret Microphone.

Comment: Oooh, another *wonderful* Instructable circuit design... *shudder*

Answer (score 3):

The replacement microphone you link to contains all the circuitry in that instructable<sup>*</sup>.  You can do away with the op-amp and all the associated stuff, and just connect it direct to the analog input of the Arduino.

---

<sup>*</sup>Actually it's better circuitry since they do it right, unlike the Destructable that is a rubbish circuit.

Comment: `Destructable`! Awesome!

Comment: @Gerben 90% of what is on Instructables is complete and utter garbage. The other 10% is my comments telling them so ;)

Comment: one more query guys,
 
As sparkfun  Electret microphone has already inbuilt op-amp, So do I need to discard op-amp circuitry in instructable site or  just proceed with op-amp circuitry ?
 confirm me.

Comment: Discard it. As I said in my answer, connect it direct to an analog input.

Comment: Thanks Majenko As you suggested I made a connection to A0 and I can see I was able to get the frequency values as my output, But I can see code is not stable at all, So could you suggest me is there any good reference code or any blog  which can help me out to get the frequency hz values as my output when I connect electret microphone to arduino.

Comment: What are you trying to get the frequency of?

Comment: Actually, I have one device on which I have to test the frequency of the sound  it generates at different operations like--success,failure..

Comment: @ferraro That really doesn't help.  What *is* the sound?  Most sound is made up of many different frequencies - even a sound that appears to be on one note.

Comment: I have builded the circuit as mentioned in instructables, Can see -1hz always as an output in serial, Could somebody help me what could be the reason